# Backend server for a GPS tracking android app

Tags: android

I'm planning to develop an android app for GPS tracking. Actually I'm a beginner in mobile app back-end server. My requirement is to store lat and long value of a authenticated user in back-end. So I need user registration, storing and retrieving of lat and long values and a GUI is needed for admin to view all user details (like active users, number of registrations, lat and long values of particular user etc.).

How can I do this? I browsed and found some results like ruby, parse.com, Google App Engine. Which is the easiest and efficient technology for my above requirements.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have to pass values from android app like User registration details, lat and long values of users current position etc. to back-end side. I know we can use JSON kind of technologies for passing values from android app to back-end. But I'm confused in the selection of proper back-end technology. Many peoples preferring ruby. So here I'm expecting an answer for my question. Sorry for my off-topic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've personally been using Parse as a back-end for my apps and its been great. Also it's pretty easy to setup and use. Though this is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Is Parse is open source?

Comment: It's closed but highly customizable in terms of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Traccar](http://www.traccar.org), it's free and open source server for GPS tracking. It supports various protocols including some HTTP based ones (e.g. [OsmAnd](http://www.traccar.org/devices/osmand.jsp))